# Cannot access external file from spark application on azure

Tags: scala, azure, hdfs, azure-blob-storage, azure-hdinsight

I've a spark-streaming application that I built using maven. I'm executing it using spark-submit from head node in hdinsight. The application uses external configuration files. But its not able to find those. I've tried using their local path, hdfs path and blob storage path (wasb). But I couldn't get it to work. Can someone suggest what is the correct way to refer to external file from an application ?

Comment: Pass config files with --files option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/bin/spark-submit 
--deploy-mode cluster 
--num-executors 1 
--files /home/sshuser/config.json,/home/sshuser/config2.json 
--class com.test.MyClass /home/sshuser/myApp.jar config.json
```

Then you can reference the files by their name only, example:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val configurationFileLocation = args(0)

    ConfigProvider.setConfiguration(Utility.loadConfiguration(configurationFileLocation))
```